# How to implement the MVC-pattern in Tkinter

Tags: python, model-view-controller, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I need a basic example where MVC pattern is used with Python TK. I have some code using Tkinter, however I would like to transform it using the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 25):

I know this is quite old but I was able to find some decent examples using the MVC pattern with both Tk and wxPython, hopefully they provide some help for anyone stumbling upon this question.

wxPython: http://wiki.wxpython.org/ModelViewController

Tk: <s>http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/ToyMVC</s>
This website no longer exists so I've hosted the code on a Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/ajfigueroa/c2af555630d1db3efb5178ece728b017).

Comment: I'm afraid your second link does't work anymore. Maybe you should delete it or re-write it if you know a new location

Comment: @madtyn I found the archive.org cache version, I've rehosted it on Gist. Let me know if that's ok? Otherwise, I'll just write the whole thing out.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an interesting example:
https://sukhbinder.wordpress.com/2014/12/25/an-example-of-model-view-controller-design-pattern-with-tkinter-python/

I would also recommend this book where the author goes through how to structure your Tkinter application in a model-view way:
https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/tkinter-gui-application-development-hotshot